# How to rest/initial-state a view after this animation?

Tags: android, animation, view, android-view, reset

As titles said I need to reset a View which is `TextView`, `ImageView` and others to it's initial state. For example after touch that particular view, an animation play and it's animation destroy(Visually) that view.

Now i need to redraw it again. Hope you got the idea. Also I've used ExplosionField effect from https://github.com/tyrantgit/ExplosionField. I've ran the code and it's working.

Here is the code:

```
private ExplosionField mExplosionField;
private TextView tv_1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv_1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext_xml);
    mExplosionField = ExplosionField.attach2Window(this);
    addListener(findViewById(R.id.root));

}

private void addListener(View root) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (root instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) root;
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            addListener(parent.getChildAt(i));
        }
    } else {
        root.setClickable(true);
        root.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mExplosionField.explode(v);
                v.setOnClickListener(null);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, by pressing "action_reset" It must draw that TextView from beginning.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_reset) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

I know the needed code goes after *"if (id == R.id.action_reset)"* but I've tried several ways which I've found through internet, but none of them worked.

[image]

**Note:**
Please go https://github.com/tyrantgit/ExplosionField and consider the example. I need to know how redraw again by pressing a button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still confused on what you meant by `destroy that view`. Resetting the view, depends on what changes you have made. Depending on that you need reverse the changes. If you have set the visibility to `Gone`, then now you need to set it to `Visible`.

So I went through the code. Add the below to your code. Things should work:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_reset) {
        View root = findViewById(R.id.root);
        reset(root);
        addListener(root);
        mExplosionField.clear();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void reset(View root) {
    if (root instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) root;
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            reset(parent.getChildAt(i));
        }
    } else {
        root.setScaleX(1);
        root.setScaleY(1);
        root.setAlpha(1);
    }
}
```

For more information, refer to the full code here: https://github.com/tyrantgit/ExplosionField/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tyrantgit/sample/MainActivity.java

Comment: Hi, destroy here not mean object destroy. if you go to the link I've put above you will have better understanding. Also I've tried whatever you said and unfortunately its now draw that view.

Comment: that was perfect. BTW how i wasn't aware of it at the time -_o  .Weird!! Anyway, Thank you.